# Multilingual top level tab in Ionic based App

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want a multilingual set of tabs, the ones that are defined in:

```
// setup an abstract state for the tabs directive
    .state('tab', {
    url: "/tab",
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: "templates/en/tabs.html"
  })
```

This is what I've tried, so far:

```
<ion-tab title="{{trans.MARKETPLACE}}" icon-off="ion-ios-gear-outline"   icon-on="ion-ios-gear" href="#/tab/market">
<ion-nav-view name="tab-market"></ion-nav-view>
</ion-tab>
```

I've tried `ng-model` as well, incidentally.

and a [toy but working, I have debug alerts in it!] Languages factory:

```
var en = {
'MARKETPLACE' : 'Marketplace',
};
var fr = {
'MARKETPLACE' : 'Marche',
};

if (lang == 'en') {
trans = en ;
} else if (lang == 'fr') {
trans = fr ;
}
var stuff = JSON.stringify(trans) ;
alert('in translate ' + stuff + ' ' + lang) ;
return trans ;
```

The Languages *do load*, from permanent storage before the main display. So 'something like this' should work? I'm aware that I could deliver the language strings in other way, but this seems pretty simple. I actually wanted `/template/language-code/stuff.html` as my web application but that doesn't seem to be the way of the app.

Thanks in advance Hugh

Comment: I would take a loot at doing something with this https://angular-translate.github.io/

Comment: Thanks, Jess, I was aware of that, but wanted something a little simpler.

Comment: I've now taken Jess' advice and re-coded this, thanks! The resulting source code is at: https://github.com/hbarnard/cclite-android-app  It's a little specialised but hopefully will help someone else.

Comment: awesome I will check it out.